# Adding port 25 to iptables won't getting to open centOS

Tags: centos, iptables, port

I am facing a problem to open port 25 with iptables on my CentOS machine. I checked the connection by 'nmap' and 'telnet' but both failed.

The follow things I did to trying make this work:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

/sbin/service iptables save

/sbin/service iptables restart
```

OUTPUTS:

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:32315 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8443 
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:25 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination      




# nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-02-08 01:46 CET
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000015s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
2222/tcp open  EtherNet/IP-1
8443/tcp open  https-alt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.16 seconds
```

Comment: How exactly do you know there is a problem?  What are you doing that is failing?  Are you trying to run a mail server, or what?  If a mail server, then are you sure it is running?  We need more details here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iptables rule is fine, but according to nmap's output I don't think that you have any service running in that port.

Confirm that by running the following command:

```
netstat -nltp | grep 25
```

If the output does not show anything in that port, be sure to start the appropriate service.